# How to get the actual configuration that spark used?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a cluster with 3 nodes (1 master and 2 workers). All the nodes are 64 GB and 16 cores. I start pyspark shell with specifying the following configuration

```
'spark.driver.memory=19g'
'spark.executor.memory=40g'
'spark.executor.instances=8'
'spark.executor.cores=5'
'spark.driver.cores=5'
'spark.default.parallelism=80'
```

Clearly, the executor memory and number executor cores are asking for resources that simply are not there. But, I am able to successfully start the shell without any exceptions. Now, when I check the number of executor instances and executor memory allocated they are 8 and 40 respectively

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf().get('spark.executor.instances')
output:
'8'
spark.sparkContext.getConf().get('spark.executor.memory')
output:
'40g'
```

Which cannot be True.

How can I know what the actual configuration is that my cluster got set up to use?

Comment: Modern operating systems use virtual memory to provide allocations larger than the available RAM and can run more than one process on a single core through timesharing. `spark.executor.memory` is an upper limit. If you load too much data, the Out-of-Memory (OOM) Killer (assuming the cluster is running Linux) will activate and crash your Spark processes.

Comment: My question is a bit different though. I want to understand the heap size and number of cores allocated to each executor when I pass such exaggerated configurations

Comment: The granted allocations are exactly those specified in your request, e.g., 40 GB per executor. If you have two executors on one node, the allocation is 80 GB in total. The system may be able to service this with 64 GB RAM and 16 GB of swap space. If it doesn't have swap space, your Spark app will crash once you fill up 64 GB of the 80 GB limit.

Comment: This is why you have to specify *sane* values for `spark.executor.memory` and make sure you are not exceeding the system limits. This is also why one usually runs Spark clusters under cluster managers such as YARN, where the admin can configure hard limits per node and you simply won't be able to launch a job that requests more than what is available.

Comment: @HristoIliev - Thank you for your time. Sorry, I have been away for a couple of days and am now asking the follow-up question. In light of your comment, is it then safe to say that one should decide upon the number of cores and number of executors and then provide a value of executor memory that is slightly below the available RAM on individual workers. This is as good a strategy as any? (If you are the only one using the cluster)

Comment: Yes, RAM is used for other applications and OS needs, so the total request for all executors on the node should be somewhat less than the total RAM. As for the CPU cores, depends on the application. If you have lots of shuffles or I/O, the CPUs will not be fully utilised and having more executor threads than available CPU cores could lead to better utilisation.